# Combinatorial Proofs for Simple Binomial Identities

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider $\sum k(k-1)(k-2)$ $n\choose k$ = $n(n-1)(n-2)$ $n-3 \choose 3$ for k >= 0 n >=3

I had initially thought the right side counted the ways to select three distinct objects from n and then choose an additional three arbitrarily from the remaining objects but I was unsure on how the LHS summation fit into the picture.  Does it make sense to choose distinguished objects for all k?  I feel like there is another identity that ties into this, where the sum $\sum$ $n \choose k$ over all k is just the same as choosing from the largest element.  Does anyone recall whether something like that exists?

Comment: The RHS should be $2^{n-3}n(n-1)(n-2)$.

Comment: Unfortunately this book disagrees with you.

Comment: Then it is incorrect.

Comment: Is it possible that there are two such identities that happen to be very similar?

Comment: @user17762 You probably mean that $2^{n-3}$ should replace the binomial coefficient on the RHS.  The other factors $n(n-1)(n-2)$ should stay as they are.

Comment: You may want to check with [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Summation+k*%28k-1%29*%28k-2%29*binom%28n%2Ck%29+from+k+%3D+0+to+n)

Comment: @user17762 My mistake, I did in fact mistype the binomial coefficient!  I fixed it now.

Comment: The equation in the original question is wrong.  For $n=5$, the left side is 240 and the right side is 600.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes. I have updated my comment to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the right hand side is $2^{n-3}$ instead of $\dbinom{n}3$. Say we want to form a baseball team from $n$ people. There can be any number of people in the team. However, the team must have a captain, vice-captain and a cheer leader (The cheer leader can be of any gender and is also a part of the team). Then there are two ways to do this.

**First method**

First choose a captain: this can be done in $n$ ways. Next choose the vice-captain: this can be done in $n-1$ ways. Then, choose the cheer leader: this can be done in $n-2$ ways. The rest of the team from the remaining $n-3$ people can be formed in $2^{n-3}$ ways. Hence, the total number of ways is $n(n-1)(n-2) \cdot 2^{n-3}$ ways.

**Second method**

First choose a team with $k$ people. Now the captain can be selected in $k$ ways, the vice-captain can be selected in $k-1$ ways and the cheer leader can be selected in $k-2$ ways. Hence, the total number of ways of forming a team with $k$ people is $$\dbinom{n}k k(k-1)(k-2)$$ Now sum this over $k$ from $3$ to $n$ to get all possible teams.

Since both the methods count the same thing, they need to be equal and hence
$$\sum_k \dbinom{n}k k(k-1)(k-2) = n(n-1)(n-2) \cdot 2^{n-3}$$

Comment: That does make perfect sense when $2^{n-3}$ replaces $n-3 \choose k$, thanks!